# What is the difference between qemu-sparc64 and qemu-system-sparc64?

Tags: qemu

I am trying to run some simple SPARC tests on bare metal QEMU. I am using `qemu-sparc64 -g 1234 simple_example` and seems to be working fine (I can connect `gdb` to `localhost:1234`, step through, etc) but was wondering what does `qemu-system-sparc64` do ? I tried running it with the same cmd line switches but got some errors. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For any QEMU architecture target, the `qemu-system-foo` binary runs a complete system emulation of the CPU and all other devices that make up a machine using that CPU type. It typically is used to run a guest OS kernel, like Linux; it can run other bare-metal guest code too.

The `qemu-foo` binary (sometimes also named `qemu-foo-static` if it has been statically linked) is QEMU's "user-mode" or "linux-user" emulation. This expects to run a single Linux userspace binary, and it translates all the system calls that process makes into direct host system calls.

If you're running `qemu-sparc64` then you are not running your program in a bare-metal environment -- it's a proper Linux userspace process, even if you're not necessarily using all of the facilities that allows. If you want bare-metal then you need `qemu-system-sparc64`, but your program needs to actually be compiled to run correctly on the specific machine type that you tell QEMU to emulate (eg the Sun4u hardware, which is the default). Also, by default `qemu-system-sparc64` will run the OpenBIOS firmware, so your bare-metal guest code needs to either run under that OpenBIOS environment, or else you need to tell QEMU not to run the BIOS (and then you get to deal with all the hardware setup that the BIOS would do for you).